# DKIM & SPF Allignment for Subdomains

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

We have a primary domain name `example.com` that has both `adkim=s` and `aspf=s` defined in its DMARC policy. Now, we have multiple subdomain names for this primary domain, such as `postman.example.com`. The subdomain has SPF, DKIM and DMARC TXT records in place.

However, when sending from `@postman.example.com` to any or most remote mail servers such as `@gmail.com`, SPF and DKIM checks pass, however, they fail their alignments. I have read up on some articles that I need to set my `adkim` and `aspf` from strict to relaxed to address this. And this I have successfully done, but `@gmail.com` still bounces with a DMARC error:

```
message": "5.7.26 Unauthenticated email from example.com is not accepted due to\n5.7.26 domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of\n5.7.26 example.com domain if this was a legitimate mail. Please visit\n5.7.26 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the\n5.7.26 DMARC initiative. t5-20020a5d5345000000b0021f10931e69si5563740wrv.234 - gsmtp",
```

This seems to be affecting all `*.example.com` subdomains. And I have no idea what else is supposed to happen for this to be fixed.

Comment: Has the TTL of the DMARC record been exceeded? Have you tried creating records for the subdomain Google is complaining about? Have you set `p=none` in the DMARC record so you can see the messages and their headers in the recipient mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

After numerous research, I finally found the solution to my own problem. Looking over the sending logs for the domain, `postman.example.com` I found that the `Sending Domain` and `From Address Domain` did not match:

- Sending Domain: `postman.example.com`
- From Address Domain: `noreply@example.com`

The messages were being rejected because of the DMARC policy that is set up for the root domain, `example.com`. Below is an example of a message from my sending logs:

```
Date: Aug 16, 2022 @ 20:42:25.578 UTC
Event: failed
---> Sending Domain: postman.example.com <---
---> From Address: Example <noreply@example.com> <---
Recipient: example@gmail.com
Subject: Test Email / #552840 - 2022-08-16T22:42:20+02:00
Message-id: 04b2f3e2e10ff16c2283a2be1fc30650@example.com

delivery-status.message: 
Unauthenticated email from example.com is not accepted due to domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of example.com domain if this was a legitimate mail. Please visit https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the DMARC initiative. t3-20020a7bc3c3000000b003a2d84a7c17si7921717wmj.14 - gsmtp
```

The security-centric goal of DMARC is to ensure that the domain in the `From` address reflects the same domain that is sending the email. As more email service providers adopt DMARC, messages that have a domain in the `From` address that differs from the sending domain will be quarantined, marked as spam, or rejected completely. Current email best practices are clear that the domain of the `From` address and sending domain should match.

Comment: This answer isn’t correct as written. ‘Sending domain’ is not a technical term in this context. What DMARC checks is that the `From:` domain in the header and the SPF-verified ‘MAIL FROM’ domain or verified DKIM signature’s domain are in alignment – and those may well be a subdomain when relaxed alignment is used.